# How to get 1920*1080 as default using Emgu.CV with 30 FPS?

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I'm trying to use Emgu.CV to display my webcam in Winform (C#).
But the default is 640*480.
I did found a way to resize(?) it as below

```
   emguCaptureDevice.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameWidth, 1920);
   emguCaptureDevice.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameHeight, 1080);
```

But the performance is very poor, like 3~5 FPS only.
Which aForge can have 1920*1080 with 30 FPS.
Sorry for poor English.
Thank you.

Comment: Is 640x480 the resolution of the camera and you want to resize the frame after capture or can the camera realy deliver frames of 1920x1080

Comment: Nah, it's the camera 1080P resolution but somehow i can only get 480P